# powershell : i cant open remote session without specify the FQDN anymore

Tags: remote-access, powershell-3.0

Some days ago, i was able do create a remote session using short name of the remote server/workstation.

This doesnt work anymore  error is :

`+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (computername1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportExcepti
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed`

but when i use the complete domain name it is working : 
`nsn computername1.domain.com`

Dns resolution is correct, what else can i check to troubleshoot this problem ?

Comment: Can you ping (`ping.exe`) the remote server without using the FQDN? How about `nslookup`? Have you tried from another location (workstation, etc) It sounds like you've got a DNS resolution issue.

Comment: @alroc yes dns resolution is ok. Starting ps with another credential on my station : same error. Connecting from another station is ok. I think i ll try to disjoin and join back the domain to see if that help.

Comment: no success after re-joining the domain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finaly found it ! :)

I had to modify the default pssession option and set the proxy to 'NoProxyServer' instead of the default value 'none'

so I added this line in my profile :

```
$PSSessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType NoProxyServer
```

From technet :

> **None**  The proxy access type is not specified. This means that proxy
> information, such as the access type, authentication mechanism, and
> credential, is not passed to the Web Services for Management (WSMan)
> protocol service. This field is introduced in Windows PowerShell 2.0.
>
> **NoProxyServer** No proxy server is used when configuring proxy settings.
> This mechanism resolves all the host names locally. This field is
> introduced in Windows PowerShell 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

As i cant find the source of the problem here is my workaround : 
rename the two aliases nsn and etsn and replace them by these functions in my profile :

```
rename-item alias:\nsn nsn2 -ea silentlycontinue
rename-item alias:\etsn etsn2 -ea silentlycontinue

function resolve-hostname{
    param($computername)
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($computername) |select -ExpandProperty hostname 
}

function nsn{
    param($computername)
    $cn=resolve-hostname $computername
    new-pssession -cn $cn
}

function etsn{
    param($computername)
    $cn=resolve-hostname $computername
    enter-pssession -cn $cn
}
```