# Powershell Invoke-Command -Computername without FQDN

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I’m using a tool which uses Invoke-Commands.
Test-Connection and other commands works without the Fully Qualified Domain Name when I type in the computer name.
But when I want to use the Invoke Commands I have the use the FQDN of the computer.
Does someone also notice that? Is this so or is the any workaround?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what happens if you use just hostname? Do you get an error message? Nothing happens? Command is executed against wrong computer? Something else?

Comment: I don’t get any error message or somethings like that. It executes the command and I don’t get any return value

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25175854/381149

Comment: @Kayasax we dont have a proxy there

Answer (score 1):

its because your WSMANconfiguration is set to credssp and not basic.

credssp requires to enter FQDN rather than netbios name

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this might provide you with the answer to your question along with why it is like that. I pretty positive that the commands share enought similarities to experience the same problem.

[Powershell remoting with ip-address as target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587426/powershell-remoting-with-ip-address-as-target)