# Powershell remoting default domain

Tags: powershell, winrm

When I try to connect to non fully qualified domain name `etsn` fails. Other commands seem to work OK.

For instance `test-connection myserver` works but `etsn myserver` doesn't unless I `etsn myserver.mydomain.com`. On other machines this works without explicit domain.

What could be a problem ? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Check your [DNS Suffix search list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/275553)

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25175854/381149

Comment: @Kayasax, awesome, thanks, that was it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell : i cant open remote session without specify the FQDN anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613497/powershell-i-cant-open-remote-session-without-specify-the-fqdn-anymore)

Comment: @Kayasax, interestingly, on other machines this is set to 'none' and it still works...

Comment: @majkinetor great, I have search a while before finding it. In my case the problem was on a workstation that used a ssh tunel, wich was confusing powershell .

Comment: This workstation I use is setup via chocolatey script just as every other one I use. The only difference is Windows 10 vs other Windows I use (7, 8, 8.1).  `etsn` worked on all by default, I didn't even know about `$PSSessionOptions`.